# Create Rows Based on Column Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I take each column for a date and create more rows with the values from that column? Basically changing the data source to be more time series. I planned to just loop through column index 4 through max index.
I want to take the data from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Comment: can you post 5-10 limes of the expected output? does `df.melt(['Province/State', 'Country/Region', 'Lat', 'Long'],var_name='Date')` serve your purpose?

Comment: Please provide your sample input and output as well as code for what you've tried so far to make a [mcve]. Please [edit] to include this information in the TEXT of your question, not as a link to an external site

Comment: Based on your edit, what I mentioned in my edit should work